# How to slice an array to get the zeroth, second, third, fourth element in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to slice an array to obtain the slice having 0,2,3, 4 th elements of two arrays in two slices. How do  I do this in python? Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide an example (ie input and desired output)

Comment: You're trying to slice one array into two slices of two arrays?  Huh?

Comment: "slice an array" ... "of two arrays in two slices" ??

Comment: I am trying to slice two different arrays with 0,2,3,4 elements into two different slices respectively. Thanks

Comment: @user1389479 Now, which of the answers was now the most helpful? Please accept that by clicking on the ✓✔ beneath it.

Answer (score 6):

```
[a[i] for i in (0, 2, 3, 4)]
```

maybe?

Comment: This was the first thing I thought of...I guess I should have posted it instead of trying to figure out how to do it in numpy ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I **single** `slice` can do it, use **two** `slice` and `concatenate` them.

```
>>> lis=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> lis[0:1]+lis[2:5]
[1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using numpy:

```
a[np.array((0,2,3,4))]
```

You need to use a numpy array for the indexing in order to trigger Advanced Indexing (using a tuple won't work).

If you perfer, you could use a list:

```
a[[0,2,3,4]]
```

That might be a little cleaner ...

Answer (score 0):

Well,if we take it literally, I think this means '*slice1 having (0,2,3, 4 th elements of two arrays in two slices2)*', which means
'*slice1 having (two slices2 each with (0,2,3, 4 th elements of its own array))*'. Which gives us

```
import operator as op
arr1 = [1,7,4,75,100,67]
arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'e', 'z', 'r', 's']
the_slice = map(op.itemgetter(0, 2, 3, 4), (arr1, arr2))
```

with the result of `list(the_slice)`:

```
[(1, 4, 75, 100), ('a', 'e', 'z', 'r')]
```

Comment: Hey ..thanks, but when I am trying this it gives me this error:the_slice = map(op.itemgetter(0, 2, 3, 4), (row1, row2))
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent